# Copying a slice of bytes into an array of non-matching size

Tags: rust

***tl;dr*** what is the fastest way to copy a slice of bytes to a local array of bytes that may or may not be the same size as the slice?

Given some slice returned from a function as a `slice_: &[u8]`. I want to copy the maximum amount of slice data to a local array of known size, `buffer: [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024]`. In other words, copy as much as possible from `slice_` to `buffer`. The `slice_` may be any length.

```rust
fn main() {
    let slice_: &[u8] = get_slice();
    let mut buffer: [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
    // copy slice_ to buffer ...
}
```

What is the fastest way to copy the slice? What is the most idiomatic way to copy the slice?

I know of function [`copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice). However, that requires

> The length of `src` must be the same as `self`.

I could iterate through the `slice_` but that seems clunky. I would guess there's a more elegant "rustic" way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```rust
pub fn kopimi(buffer: &mut [u8; 1024], slice: &[u8]) {
    let n = std::cmp::min(buffer.len(), slice.len());
    buffer[0..n].copy_from_slice(&slice[0..n]);
}
```

with optimisations on [assembles into four instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/1E15exbjf): a compare, load-immediate, conditional move and tail-call to `memcpy`:

```
example::kopimi:
        cmp     rdx, 1024
        mov     eax, 1024
        cmovae  rdx, rax
        jmp     qword ptr [rip + memcpy@GOTPCREL]
```

I don’t think you can get much more efficient than that.

Comment: The link to the assembly is very cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The same length requirement isn't that hard since you can just reslice:

```rust
fn main() {
    let slice: Box<[u8]> = get_slice();
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 1024];
    let l = slice.len().min(buffer.len());
    buffer[..l].copy_from_slice(&slice[..l]);
}
```

Note: I changed from `Box<&[u8]>` to `Box<[u8]>` because it's less indirection and there is really no need for a `Box<&[u8]>` that I can imagine anywhere.